# LLVM 3.0 or later required. Your system has version 10.0.1 installed

Tags: 20.04

I'm trying to build the smatch from its latest code.

I'm getting following error on executing make command.

```
Makefile:116: LLVM 3.0 or later required. Your system has version 10.0.1 installed
```

Because I'm not able to make the smatch without this error. I'm having issue in building the smatch.

I'm not sure, where there is a hole in the thinking.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1482053/edit) your question and add more details like what you are trying to build.  Please DO NOT use the comment section for details but add them to your question.  The more details you can give us the more helpful we can be.  Unfortunately, as your question stands we can only take guesses.